# How to use set_caption with flextables in lapply

Tags: r, lapply, flextable

I have the following list of flextables

```
mini = list(airquality, mtcars)
```

I am wondering how to assign titles to them via `lapply` (I already know how to do this via `for loop`)

I have tried something like

```
titles = c('airquality', 'mtcars')
i = 1:2
lapply(mini, function(x) x %>% flextable() %>% set_caption(titles[i]))
```

However, it does not seem to work fine. How could I assign properly titles via lapply?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similiar to a `for` loop you could loop over an index vector when using `lapply`  like so:

```
mini <- list(airquality, mtcars)

titles <- c("airquality", "mtcars")

library(flextable)

lapply(
  seq_along(mini),
  function(x) {
    mini[[x]] %>%
      flextable() %>%
      set_caption(titles[[x]])
  }
)
```